# Flutter Dart : Can not run apk build release Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, build, apk, release

I build APK release from Flutter source code and run it's show error below.but run debug it work normally.Any one help me.Thanks.[image]

Comment: Use null check operator ,you can  run << flutter analyze >> and find the code line

Comment: Can you show the code block that cause this error?

Comment: I run apk release .because run debug it's work normally and don't where know code block error .